# Is it possible to add a sidebar in a woocommerce hook?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to add a sidebar to woocommerce woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook. I'm using the following code in the functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar', 1);
function my_custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar() {
      echo get_sidebar('my_custom_sidebar');
}
```

The problem that I got is that it displays the wordpress default sidebar instead of the sidebar with the my_custom_sidebar id.

is there a way to accomplish this?
thanks!

Ah by the way, I'm registering the sidebar like this :

```
/**
 * Register sidebars
*/
function meir_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'My Custom Sidebar',
        'id' => 'my_custom_sidebar',
        'description' => 'Sidebar for top filters.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '<div class="clear"></div></div></div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3><div class="filter_box"><div class="filter_wrapper">',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'meir_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: There is an add on called WooSidebars, maybe look into that. Other than that, I suspect your `'my_custom_sidebar'` is not being registered properly. Additional code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I actually figured it out. Leaving the code in case someones need it later:

```
// Add sidebar for shop loop header  
function my_custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar() {

dynamic_sidebar('shop-loop-header-sidebar');

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar', 2);
```